# "EventLabels" option no longer working for TradingChart in 11.3

Tags: plotting, charts, finance

I used `EventLabels`option with `TradingChart` and `CandlestickChart` functions in Ma 11.1. I recently updated to Ma 11.3. The option does not work anymore. Even the examples provided in documentation do not work. For example, either of the the following codes does not produce the exact chart given in the documentation. Any help to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
TradingChart[
 {"GOOGL", {{2010, 1, 1}, {2010, 1, 15}}}, 
 EventLabels -> {{2010, 1, 6} -> Column[{"\[UpArrow]", "label"}, Center]}
]

CandlestickChart[
 {"IBM", {{2010, 1, 1}, {2010, 1, 15}}}, 
 EventLabels -> {{2010, 1, 6} -> Column[{"\[UpArrow]", "label"}, Center]}
]
```

Comment: This won't help you particularly, but I tested your code in MMA 11.2, and it still works fine.

Comment: I think they will fix this in the upcoming release. Thank you.

Comment: Ran into the same danged problem in 11.3. The least they could do if they kill an option in a new version is to put a note in the documentation. @DanielLichtblau

Comment: @MarkAdler What makes you think they did it on purpose? Looking over the code, I don't see any indication that they tried to remove it - something probably just got broken